# constructing new variable with specific threshold

Tags: r

I need to construct an index/new variable out of 5 different variables (all dummies) in R. How can I set different thresholds for this new variable to either have the outcome "true" or not? Such as if 2 out of these 5 variables take the value 1, then the index/new variable takes the value 1 (it doesn't matter which two of the 5 variables take the value 1...)

This is the code we used for the threshold 1 out of 5:

```
dta$new.variable[dta$variable1==1|dta$variable2==1|dta$variable3==1|dta$variable4==1|dta$variable5==1| = 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. Please format your code properly, it is simply unusuable like this. This will increase the chances of getting a quick and correct answer for you! Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You may be after rowSums() to allow you to do:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 0, 1),
                 b = c(0, 0, 1))

df$total <- rowSums(df)

df$state <- ifelse(df$total >= 2, TRUE, FALSE)
```